# Как правильно определить свой уровень знаний?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

На данный момент имея 2.5 года практики в веб программировании убеждаюсь что знания временем не измеряются как и зп тоже. Хотялось бы как-то определить на что же знаю я и на что можно претендовать. На данный момент интересует именно стандартное разграничения как junior,middle,senior.

Если я тут не по теме, прошу простить и поправить.

Comment: на мете [уже обсуждали подобное](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4713/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-engineer-%D0%B8-senior)

Answer (score 1):

Разошлите свое портфолио работодателям, выполните несколько тестовых заданий, пройдите несколько собеседований. После этого у вас сложится вполне ясная картина - на сколько вы разбираетесь в своей области, подходят ли ваши знания спросу рынка. Если есть какие-то очевидные пробелы, то вы их определенно таким образом найдете. Ведь по сути, в данном случае, ценность знаний определяется тем, захочет ли кто-то платить вам за них деньги. Если нет, то они получаются бесполезны. Изучайте рынок труда, старайтесь соответствовать тем требованиям которые чаще всего упоминаются работодателями, старайтесь получить те знания за которые готовы больше платить.